# Domain redirecting to wrong S3 bucket

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services

I'm currently trying to set up a small static website with my domain from NameCheap using AWS S3, but I'm having trouble correctly pointing requests to the corresponding S3 bucket.

These are my configurations for the services I use:

**NameCheap**

```
CNAME         www  example.com.s3-website-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com.
URL Redirect  @    http://www.example.com/
```

**AWS S3**

```
Static Hosting example.com.s3-website-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com.
```

I am fairly new to web hosting/domain stuff so please bear with me, but from what I understand from my registrar configuration is: users entering the naked domain `example.com` are redirected to `www.example.com` which then points to the AWS S3 bucket. Then the *CNAME* record then points to the corresponding AWS bucket.

Howeverwhen I try to visit `www.example.com` I somehow get pointed to the `www.example.com` bucket instead of the `example.com` bucket landing me to the *AWS Bucket not found* page.

**Extra Details**

1. I've checked with DNS Checker that `www.example.com`'s CNAME record indeed points to `example.com.s3-website-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com.`.
2. I've also tried making a `www.example.com` bucket then redirecting it to `example.com` but it seems it points to the actual domain instead of the bucket therefore causing a redirect loop. `example.com->www.example.com->www.example.com (Bucket)->example.com->∞`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bucket name must exactly match the hostname pointing to it in DNS.  Create a bucket called www.example.com and point your www record to it.

Comment: A few hours after posting my question and not getting any answers I just decided to exactly do this. I've read the docs and saw no mention of this, must've missed it but thanks for confirming.

Comment: [*"Because Amazon S3 sees only the original host name www.example.com and is unaware of the CNAME mapping used to resolve the request, the CNAME and the bucket name must be the same."*](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/VirtualHosting.html)