# Subdomain pointing to deleted S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloudflare, s3fs

I am stuck in my present (AP-SOUTH) and deleted (US-EAST) S3 bucket.

I had mistakenly created a bucket in US-EAST (cdn.example.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com) and mapped my subdomain - **cdn.example.com**

I allowed read public access and added the following policy to US-EAST S3 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteAccessPermissionsReqd.html

Then i tested it by placing a test.txt file and http://cdn.example.com/test.txt

It was success. Also tried using https://cdn.example.com/test.txt using Flexible SSL inside your CloudFlare. It was success too.

Afterwards When i realized my mistake, i deleted the US-EAST bucket and created AP-SOUTH S3 bucket **(with same bucket name)** (cdn.example.com.s3-website.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com) and pointed the **same subdomain** cdn.example.com to it and accordingly updated the DNS at cloudflare.

But now even after 42 hours, my subdomain cdn.example.com is still pointing to deleted bucket US-EAST.

Am i missing something here? Any pointers will be appreciated.
Just in case, I am using S3FS-FUSE with magento.

**Proper error is as below as requested:-**

404 Not Found
Code: NoSuchBucket
Message: The specified bucket does not exist
BucketName: cdn.example.com
RequestId: 0E46EDA9081940FC
HostId: WnxB9/4C8uQi8k81rEX/FZSFa6s8w6Xt6ohIV3tec6BCg8VHfyaps2MPrw8qfX6/Jpba+fmNCUA=

Comment: How have you checked that `cdn.domain.com` is pointing to wrong entity? What is the TTL of the entry? I am also wondering why don't you simply use Cloudflare for caching and your own server as the source server...

Comment: Because when i am now accessing the test file at new bucket with the url, it says no bucket with this name... I am using AWS for my media folder sync as i am using S3FS

Comment: You need to check your DNS entry first, where it does point to from different places you can check.

Comment: The problem as you have described it should not be possible, so will be difficult to troubleshoot this unless you can tell us the subdomain and the name of the bucket.  *"it says no bucket with this name"*  It is very important not to paraphrase error messages.  Always use the *exact* text of the error, please.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot - I have edited my question and defined the error properly. I have rechecked that DNS settings are proper in my cloudflare for the new S3 bucket

Comment: Well, this doesn't seem related to the region.  It looks as if you didn't actually name the new bucket `cdn.example.com` exactly the same as the hostname you've pointed to it.  It must be exactly that, for home-based virtual hosting to work.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot - I accept your answer. I made all DNS changes from scratch. Now it is working fine. May be i have missed the "Exact same name" thing, but i had this in my mind. Ref > https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168926-How-do-I-use-CloudFlare-with-Amazon-s-S3-Service-
> https://serverfault.com/a/886554